# Flash AS3 - How to duplicate dynamic html content box and call different data?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I know it's gonna be difficult without being hands on, but here it goes...

I'm working in Flash CS5 w/ActionScripting 3.0. I have a content box w/scroller that calls dynamic html on one page/part of my project's timeline.

I want to duplicate the exact same content box w/scroller, but need it to contain different data (call a different .htm doc), for another part of my site.

I'm kinda new to this and am not sure how to modify the script or files. I got the scroller as an independent project from activeden (or flash components). I'm about to just append a # to every single piece of the original scroller project.. There must be an easier way..

Comment: what is a "content box w/scroller" -- that's not a standard flash component that I'm aware of... can you show code, or give us any other information to work with?

Answer (score 0):

Practically your content box should be an instance of a class. if you have a fla, it should be possible to link your scroller to a class and implement some methods. Then , each time you need a new content box, you simply do this:

```
  var box:ContentBox = new ContentBox();
  addChild( box );
```

I'm not quite sure if your scroller comes with a content box or not, but if it doesn't , just create your ContentBox class and add your scroller to it by more or less doing the same as explained above